# Deserialize XML file with flexible number of attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

I have an xml file, where some nodes can have a flexible number of attributes, all starting with the same prefix:

```
<node a1="" a2="" ... an=""></node>
```

1. How can I reflect this in the XML Schema?
2. What's the best approach for deserializing such xml file into an object in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, you can't reflect that directly in XML Schema; each attribute has to be declared, by name. You could express it in Schematron, but not in DTD or XSD; not certain about RelaxNG.

If the idea is to declare "any attribute whose name is 'a' followed by a number", that's a lot like trying to declare a similar set of variables in a programming language, or fields in a database. There's rarely a way to do "meta" declaration for a (potentially infinite) set like that.

If you can impose a maximum, like 99 such attributes, you can declare all of those individually -- but that's pretty ugly, and there's no guarantee that an element will use them in order.

If the values of these attributes are just tokens (numbers, names, or similar), the "XML-ish" way would be to declare one attribute, of type IDREFS or NMTOKENS, which allows any number of such tokens within the value.

Once you've got the values, as Soontz said an array or possibly dictionary/hash would be a sensible place to keep them.

Answer (score 2):

On your second question - you might want to store those nodes in e.g. array of strings or in `Dictionary<string,string>` that maps attribute names to values, use `XmlSerializer` for serialization, and implement `IXmlSerializable` interface in your class to read and write the XML manually.